# Google Classroom Pub/Sub registration returning 403 authentication error

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-classroom

I'm developing a php application using Google Classroom, and keep getting  a  "code": 403, "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes." error.

Here's what I've done so far, any help would be tremendous!

- I've set up my app oauth permissions to use auth/classroom.push-notifications
- I've set 'classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com' to have the  Pub/Sub Publisher role
- I've set up a Pub/Sub topic

Here's the code I'm using:

```php
$google_course_id = '123456';
$topic_name       = 'projects/my-app-name/topics/TopicName';
$feed_type        = 'COURSE_WORK_CHANGES';

$user = User::find(2); // User who has authorized via OAuth and accepted all permissions

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessToken($user->get_google_social_token());
$classroom = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
$pub_sub = new Google_Service_Classroom_CloudPubsubTopic();
$pub_sub->setTopicName($topic_name);

$work_changes_info = new Google_Service_Classroom_CourseWorkChangesInfo();
$work_changes_info->setCourseId($google_course_id);

$feed = new Google_Service_Classroom_Feed();
$feed->setCourseWorkChangesInfo($work_changes_info);
$feed->setFeedType($feed_type);

$registration = new Google_Service_Classroom_Registration();
$registration->setCloudPubsubTopic($pub_sub);
$registration->setFeed($feed);

$classroom->registrations->create($registration);
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the 403 error.

Any help in identifying what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you be encountering one of the 'PERMISSION_DENIED' issues?https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/registrations/create

Comment: It could be, but in that case I don't think I'd be getting the "Insufficient authentication scopes" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.  While I remembered to add the push-notification scope to my google developer console, I forgot to add them to the Oauth linking code.  Adding it to the bottom seems to have fixed the issue!

```php
return Socialite::driver('google')
            ->scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.students.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.push-notifications',
            ])
            ->with(['access_type' => 'offline', 'prompt' => 'consent select_account'])
            ->redirect();
```